# tolower invalid multibyte string - ignore escapes

Tags: r

I realize this question has been asked before, but after searching for a long time I haven't found an answer that satisfies my needs. The solutions for all other posts regarding this topic are to either encode the special-characters or remove them completely, so I do not think this is a duplicate.

I have a ton of files from different sources that are all encoded differently. Therefore, I want to read all strings "exactly as they are" (ignore escapes), so that I can map them correctly after I scrub the data. As a part of my mapping, I change all characters to lowercase, but `tolower` doesn't work with escape characters.

Example of error:

```
tolower("ThIs d\xf6ESn't W\xf6Rk")
>>> Error in tolower("ThIs d\xf6ESn't W\xf6Rk") : invalid multibyte string 1
```

I realize that I could change the encoding to get rid of the error, but like I said before, I don't want to convert the characters because there isn't an encoding that could work for all sources. I need the strings to be read as is.

E.G. this isn't acceptable:

```
tolower(iconv("ThIs d\xf6ESn't W\xf6Rk", "WINDOWS-1252", "UTF-8"))
>>> "this döesn't wörk"
```

Or maybe it is acceptable if there's an easy way to change the "ö" back to a "\xf6".

At the end of the day, what I want is this:

```
NEWtolower("ThIs d\xf6ESn't W\xf6Rk")
>>> "this d\xf6esn't w\xf6rk"
```

Is there an easy way to just ignore escapes? As a hack I was thinking of recreating the string by looping through each character, turning to lower case, and then putting the characters back together again. But even `nchar("ThIs d\xf6ESn't W\xf6Rk")` gives me an error, so I really don't know what to do.

There has to be an easy way to just ignore escapes right? `read.csv()` has an `allowEscapes = TRUE` option. Any hacky method to get this to work would be acceptable.

Comment: But what exactly is "lower" would be determined by the encoding and locale. And you can't tell the number of characters of a string if you don't know the encoding because some encodings use multiple bytes per character. Why are you trying to keep the escaped byte representation? What could you possibly do next with a bunch of strings of mixed encoding? I don't understand what the real goal here is.

Comment: As an example say from 3 sources I get 3 different spellings of names: `Brandon`, `Brandön`, and `Brand\xf6n`. I have a separate csv that maps all these to just `Brandon`. `tolower` is necessary for misspellings from the various sources. Sounds like I need to find a solution that involves encoding  `Brand\xf6n` to `Brandön` first, huh? Man this is going to suck, there are just so many different encodings these sources use that I don't have control over, and I haven't found a one-size-fits-all encoding (at least 5 different languages).

Comment: Well, on my OS `"Brand\xf6n" == "Brandön"` returns TRUE. Those are exactly the same string, just with a different way of representing the non-ascii characters of the string. Are you sure you really have different encoding of the data? Or just different on-screen representations? How are you importing this data?

Comment: Interesting, `"Brand\xf6n" == "Brandön"` returns `FALSE` for me. I read-in data with `read.csv(..., allowEscapes = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. I've tried all the different freads and the like, but nothing has solved it. This method has worked for me the last few months, but just yesterday new data has caused this error. There are over 5.5 million rows and it's updated (read: there are new mistakes) daily, so it's not plausible to scrub manually.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: MacOS Sierra version 10.12.6

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a [common problem](https://github.com/xia-lab/MetaboAnalystR/issues/19) with how Linux deals with the encoding of strings. Try converting the string to UTF-8 and it should work:

```
txt <- "ThIs d\xf6ESn't W\xf6Rk"

# change encoding
txt <- iconv(txt, from = 'ISO-8859-1', to = 'utf8')

tolower(txt)

> "this döesn't wörk"
```